# angularjs filter to convert to valid directive name

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I want to write filter that turns for example:

'selectSingle'

into this:

'select-single'

That is for me to build custom directives in the ng-repeat process which excepts the 'selectSingle' value, and so.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would do it:

```
.filter('camelToHtml', function(){
    var re = /[A-Z]/g;
    return function(camelCase){
        return camelCase.replace(re, function(match, index, original){
            return "-" + match.toLowerCase()
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: I just updated the answer. I forgot to add the RegExp that you will need. It is there now.